# Converting an XML serialization back to java code

Tags: java, code-generation, xml-deserialization

I know this questions might seem a little odd, but I want to make sure.
One of my superiors is kind of convinced that there is a more or less easy way to convert the XML serialization of an object back to the java code that created it. I am, however, pretty sure that the best I can get is the object.

So basically my questions is: Is there any way to convert something like this

```
<java version="1.6.0_10" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder"> 
 <object class="javax.swing.JPanel"> 
  <void property="size"> 
   <object class="java.awt.Dimension"> 
    <int>42</int> 
    <int>23</int> 
   </object> 
  </void> 
 </object> 
</java>
```

back to something like

```
JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
jPanel.setSize(42,23);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If he's convinced, he should know how to do it :). I know I'm not helping, but managers who don't know how to code, shouldn't suggest how to code.

Comment: @Augusto: It is not clear from the question, if the superior is only a manager or managing developer, but I agree that in that case he should provide more hints on how to do that, not just some 'gut feeling' and require that.

Comment: I think Augusto is right. There's alway more to a solution than just the "can-do". If the runtime complexity is bad, it can bring down the whole application. Can-do is the first step, but after that there's always the effects on the current project.

Comment: I agree, partially. But we do not know anything about the whole problem / context of the application. If it is beneficial to have the objects stored in XML format, it should be at least considered. There seems to be even already pre-determined way of deserializing the object, using the XMLDecoder, encoded in the above-mentioned XML.

Comment: a simple bean like the example can be transformed easily via xslt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided that all serialized objects comply to the java beans contract, you can re-create the process that the XML de-serializer follows to unmarshal the java objects, in order to recreate the code that goes with it.

Back in the golden XML days, I worked some projects that used similar processes to generate Java code from XML definitions.

Departing from your serialized model, you can use a XSL-T transformation to recreate the code that lead to the serialized objects. This process will create very linear code (as in non-modular), but you'll have what you're looking for.

An example to get you started: To process the XML you provided, you can use the following recursive transformation: copy/paste it & try it here: [online XSL-T](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog) *(the template is based on Xpath 1.0 to be able to use the online tool. Xpath 2.0 will improve the code in some areas, like string functions)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">

  <xsl:template match="object">
     <xsl:call-template name="objectClass" /> <xsl:value-of select="string(' ')" /> 
     <xsl:call-template name="objectNodeName" />
     = new <xsl:call-template name="objectClass" />(<xsl:call-template name="objectParams" />);

  <xsl:for-each select="*[@property]">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
    <xsl:call-template name="setProperty" />
  </xsl:for-each>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/" >
   <xsl:apply-templates match="/object" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()" />

  <xsl:template name="objectNodeName">
    <xsl:param name="node" select="." />
    <xsl:value-of select="translate($node/@class,'.','_')" />_<xsl:value-of select="count($node/ancestor-or-self::*)" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="setProperty">
    <xsl:call-template name="objectNodeName" > <xsl:with-param name="node" select="parent::node()"/></xsl:call-template>
.set<xsl:call-template name="capitalize"><xsl:with-param name="str" select="@property"/></xsl:call-template>(<xsl:call-template name="objectNodeName" > <xsl:with-param name="node" select="node()"/></xsl:call-template>);
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="objectClass">
    <xsl:param name="fqn" select="@class" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$fqn" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="objectParams">
    <xsl:for-each select="*[not(child::object)]">
     <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">,</xsl:if><xsl:value-of select="." />
     </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:variable name="smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
  <xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />

  <xsl:template name="capitalize">
    <xsl:param name="str" select="." />
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(translate(substring($str,1,1),$smallcase,$uppercase),substring($str,2))">
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Disclaimer: I tested the template on the sample provided and some variations of it, including some containign several more objects. I did not test deeper object nesting. It's an example and not a fully-functional [XML Serialization](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/persistence3/) to Java transformation, which is left as an exercise to the reader :-)

Comment: This one sounds like what I am looking for, but I can't get your example to work. Firstly, the online tool complains about an unclosed tag in line 50 (xsl:value-of), which is easy to fix. However, whether I do that or not, I get a blank result (I used my provided example for testing).

Comment: Ok, I used another online XSL-T tool and it produced java code that wasn't pretty (I wasn't expecting that), but it worked. Thanks a lot, I hope I'll be able to put it to use :)

Comment: @Malhelo ref error: extrange, a direct copy/paste from the code here to the tool referenced in my answer worked with no problems. Did you select the whole code before copying?  Code generated will be certainly not pretty and very linear. You'll see fully qualified class names, long object names, etc... It's much like decompiled code. I warned about the linearity. I should have warned you about the code ugliness as well.

Comment: Neither the ugliness nor the linearity are a problem to me.
However, are you sure that
`<xsl:value-of select="concat(translate(substring($str,1,1),$smallcase,$uppercase),substring($str,2))">` doesn't need to be closed? Because that was the error the tool complained about...

Comment: @Malhelo you're right. It's missing a closing tag. Which XSL-T tool are you using? It seems to report better errors that the one of w3cshool linked above (which was a PITA)

Comment: I've tried two:
1) [php-based](http://www.shell-tools.net/index.php?op=xslt)
2) [java applet](http://unindented.org/projects/xslt-tester-applet/run/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think there are several ways to implement this. First of all you can use JAXB technology, read about it http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html#xmp1.
Second way: you always can read xml in runtime (DOM, SAX) and create objects dynamically using reflection.

Answer (score 0):

It is not that difficult. I am not sure how this would work with Swing class like `JPanel`, but since it is a Java bean, it should not be a problem to use some kind of XML library like [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html), which is one of the easiest way of how to do such things. Or you could use more verbose JAXB or [XML Beans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/).

**Edit:** I'm sorry I didn't notice that there already is an XMLDecoder mentioned, and [there seems to be](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-read-a-javabean-from-an-xml-file-using-xmldecoder.html) an article on how to 'read JavaBean from XML file using XMLDecoder'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible because if object class can be everything, how would you know what method to call to set size x to 42? Maybe there is a setter for this, maybe just a constructor or the number was calculated somehow.

The only possibility I can imagine is through the use of reflection, that's more or less the same frameworks like XStream do. So you can create the same object, but not the same code that was originally used to create it.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the superiors belief was poorly articulated and/or poorly understood.  In particular, "the XML serialization of an object" may have been meant to refer to the schema, not the XML for a particular object, so that "convert the XML serialization of an object back to the java code that created it" would mean going from schema to marshalling code - JAXB's XJC, or similar.

Answer (score -1):

I have never seen any sort of generalized technology that can reliably reconstruct the actual **code instructions** used to create an object based on a general XML serialization. What you have is stuff like JAXB, XStream or xmlbeans that can recreate an **object** based on XML serialized information. This is pretty evident when you think about it since there can be any number of ways to code an object to a specific state. Just knowing the state (which is really what the XML serialization is - the object's state at a certain point in time) is not enough to deduce HOW the object got to that state.

Also, there are many types of information that is transient in nature and not serializable (thread handles, sockets, window handles, device context etc etc etc) so serialization is not applicable to all objects/classes to begin with.

Comment: This is certainly not a generalized case. It's specific to java beans encoding/decoding and the use of XMLDecoder as the code sample clarifies. See http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/persistence3/